# In my laragon I entered my root then I have entered my project I want to enter my terminal but have not worked

Tags: laragon

In my laragon I entered my root then I have entered my project then I have do right click in side my project then I press terminal but it has not worked  I want to enter my terminal but have not worked.I was expecting My terminal to open but it has not open and it supposed to open a terminal